# Getting an "IndexError: list index out of range" that does not make sense to me

Tags: python-2.7, list, loops, pdf, for-loop

I have an assignment to do based on taking the Gadsby story, removing all the punctuation, and replacing the "o" with "0"s. With the words in the story I then have to crack a PDF which is in the format w1w2w3 and keeps on rising (w2w3w4, w3w4w5, w4w5w6, etc.) with a loop until the password is found. My problem is I'm getting an IndexError: list index out of range on the following line

```
password = word_list[list_1] + word_list[list_2] + word_list[list_3]
```

Helping find the reason for the error would be greatly appreciated as I've been looking at it for the last 2 days with no avail. If you notice any other errors in my code too please point them out also.

```
import re
import PyPDF2

# Defining the function called "pdf_cracker"
def pdf_cracker():
    # Import the shuffle
`   from random import shuffle
    # Open Gadsby story and define it as the variable "string"
    string = open("gadsby.txt", "r").read()
    # Uses substitution in the RE module to only include characters from a-z, A-Z and 0-9
    new_str = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ",string)
    open("gadsby_no_punctuation.txt", "w").write(new_str)
    gadsby_no_punctuation = open("gadsby_no_punctuation.txt", "r").read().split()

    word_list = [gadsby_no_punctuation]

    list_1 = 0
    list_2 = 1
    list_3 = 2


for item in word_list:          
    password = word_list[list_1] + word_list[list_2] + word_list[list_3] # ERROR ON THIS LINE
    password = password.replace("o", "0")
    password = password.replace("O", "0")
    print password

    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
    pdf_file = ("crack_me.pdf", "rb")

    if pdf.isEncrypted == False:
        print "The file you're trying to crack doesn't have a password"

    if(pdf_file.decrypt(password) == 1):
        print "O " + password + " is the password!"
        break

    else:       
        print "X " + password + " is not the password"
        list_1 = list_1 + 1
        list_2 = list_2 + 1
        list_3 = list_3 + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    zip_cracker() # Ignore this line - this is another part of the program, not throwing up any errors.
    pdf_cracker()
```

Comment: You are assigning 5 every time. Check out: http://pythontutor.com

Comment: I think that is what's happening

Comment: Am I? Where so?

Comment: see if link helps

Answer (score 0):

you're creating the gadsby list and then putting it inside another list

```
gadsby_no_punctuation = "a b c d e f g".split() # A test string
>>> gadsby_no_punctuation
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> word_list = [gadsby_no_punctuation]
>>> word_list
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']] # a list inside a list
>>> len(word_list)
1 # only 1 item in the list
```

Instead of

```
word_list = [gadsby_no_punctuation]
```

Copy the gadsby list by using [:]

```
word_list = gadsby_no_punctuation[:]
```

As long as there are at least 3 words you should no longer get that error